# Documentation of Magic Methods in Python

Tags: python

I've been reading various style guides for python (PEP 8 and so on), and have not found a definitive answer for a rather simple question.

When redefining one of Python's numerous magic methods, such as `__str__(self)`, `__le__(self, other)` and others, should the re-defined method be documented? Or is it sufficient to assume that the developer will look up the existing documentation on python.org?

This is different from other code mostly because many magic methods are invisible. For examples if I define `__eq__(self, other)`, the end user never sees the internal docstring when calling it via `==`

Comment: Special methods are not special when it comes to documentation. If you expect the API user to need to know about the method, document.

Comment: I think I read this in another question: **it is not necessary to document them**, because these methods already have a predefined behavior, which shouldn't be changed.

Comment: That said, this is primarily opinion based, so voting to close as such.

Comment: The general gist of the question is as @Christian noted. Also, the main problem with magic methods is there generally is no easy way to know about the method's existence, unless you are digging around in the actual code.

Comment: @mleyfman: That's not accurate as far as Python is concerned; you can exhaustively list all object names with `dir` and/or `getattr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean documenting what it does, you only need to do so if the operation can ["astonish"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). If you mean documenting how it works, then you should always do so.